# Where to define liquid method for :url from attached file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

Posts on my blog have several pictures

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The pictures have an attached imagefile, I use the gem paperclip to manage this.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post

    has_attached_file :image,
        :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
        :url  => "/images/:id/:filename",
        styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>"  } 

    do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

I can create image tags easily with `<%= image_tag picture.image.url %>`
so picture.image.url returns the url where the image is stored. I'm trying to get this url as well with the liquid templating gem.
I want to do something like

```
{% for picture in pictures %} 
<li style="background-image:'{{picture.image.url(:medium)}}';"></li>  
{% endfor %}
```

I'm guessing I need a liquid method `:url`, but I have no model to write it (since `image` is an attached file, not a model). Does someone know how I could get the image url trough liquid?

Comment: What gem do you use for liquid serialization, and how do you run the serialization?

Comment: in my gemfile I just have gem "liquid"
And I would run the serialization with something like
        `markdown = Liquid::Template.parse(text).render("pictures" => @post.pictures)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way to do that is to manually serialize your pictures:

```
# ruby code
Liquid::Template.parse(text).render("pictures" => @post.pictures.map{|p| {'id' => p.id, 'medium_image_url' => p.image.url(:medium)})

# liquid code
{% for picture in pictures %} 
  <li style="background-image:'{{picture.medium_image_url}}';"></li>  
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to separate serialization into separate module, you can move it to [`ActiveModel::Serializer`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or [`Liquid::Drop`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Introduction-to-Drops). `ActiveModel::Serializer` is a good decision if you also use JSON (or XML) serialization, otherwise `Liquid::Drop` is preferable choice (it was specifically made for serialization to liquid). Here is modified example from `Liquid::Drop` docs:

```
# Ruby code

class PictureDrop < Liquid::Drop
  def initialize(picture)
    @picture = picture
  end

  def id
    @picture["id"]
  end

  def image_urls
    {
      'medium' => @picture.image.url(:medium),
      'thumb' => @picture.image.url(:thumb)
    }
  end
end

markdown = Liquid::Template.parse(text).render("pictures" => @post.pictures.map{|p| PictureDrop.new(p)})

# liquid code

{% for picture in pictures %} 
    <li style="background-image:'{{picture.image_urls['medium']}}';"></li>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write me this solution EugZol, it does exactly what I want!

Comment: You are welcome! If you liked my answer, consider upvoting as well :)